# How would I implement Google's default material example?

Tags: android, material-design

So, on [google.com/design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#) Google uses the following mockup:

[image: mockup]

How would I archive something like this? 
It obviously uses Fragments, I guess with the Cardsview / Recyclerview widgets from the support library.

But I didn't manage to archive a design that presents my content in this exact way. Is there some kind of default template to get me started? Would you have any hints? 
There are lots of tutorials for fragments on the internet, but none to use the exact material design as in the mockup.

I'm new to Android development (but not development in general) and want to follow the official guidelines, but it seems quite hard to archieve. 
The only reference from Google to some code I could Google I/O app, but that's rather complex. I can't understand why Google wouldn't provide a default template which includes all those nice material theme elements which you could use as a base to tinker around.

Comment: What problem, specifically, did you have when implementing the design, and how did what you got differ from the result you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your frustration considering I am no designer. I have a couple of repositories that implement material design on [GitHub](https://github.com/EugeneHoran?tab=repositories). Fragments would be a completely different question so I am posting code just within the main activity.
A working example to match the mobile based image you posted.

[image: Google Material Design]

**Styles**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**dimens**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="fab_button_diameter">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_button_margin_bottom">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_button_margin_right">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="elevation_low">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="elevation_high">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Colors**

```
<resources>
    <color name="light_blue">#00bbd2</color>
    <color name="dark_blue">#0097a7</color>
    <color name="yellow">#eeff41</color>
    <color name="yellow_clicked">#50eeff41</color>
    <color name="white">#fafafa</color>
    <color name="dark_grey">#6d6d6d</color>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"/>

    <!-- Main Content-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Material"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_image_button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_button_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_button_margin_right"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_shape"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewsById();
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Material Design");
        ImageButton fab_image_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_image_button);
        fab_image_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Floating Action Button** create a file in drawables folder called fab_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <!-- Shadow -->
            <item android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp">
                <layer-list>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="3px"
                                android:left="3px"
                                android:right="3px"
                                android:top="3px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                </layer-list>
            </item>

            <!-- Blue button pressed -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/yellow_clicked"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">

        <layer-list>
            <!-- Shadow -->
            <item android:top="2dp" android:right="1dp">
                <layer-list>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="4px"
                                android:left="4px"
                                android:right="4px"
                                android:top="4px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                </layer-list>
            </item>

            <!-- Blue button -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </item>
</selector>
```

**Final Result**

[image: Final Result]

**UPDATE**

Here is the Tablet Variation.

**xlarge\activity_main.xml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/extendedSpace"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"/>


    <!-- RecyclerView Here
    - the margin for the right and left need to greater than 88dp so it does not interfere with the floating action button
    - Just using a cardview as an example of how it would look
    -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="88dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_image_button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_button_margin_right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_shape"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**Making Other Screen Sizes**
Go to the circled red and choose Create "..." Variation. In case you don't know to to create other layout variations. Cheers!!
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is pretty awesome. But this will look exactly the same on a tablet, just very big, correct?
Now I'm still wondering how to achieve the view in Google's mockup for the tablet format. That seems to be the really tricky part to have a consistent material design style over different device categories.

Comment: @tony  Everything will work exactly the same on the tablet but I suggest you make a layout designed for the tablet to format it properly for the tablet.  Another thing to think about is the icons in which you include in your project.  The images change size automatically depending on the screen size.

Comment: @tony The table version is going to use a recyclerview in the layout.  I will have a look at it and get back to you to see if I can post a simple version of it

Comment: Yes, that I get. But it doesn't look like the example in the middle of the mockup, does it? With the wider toolbar and the cropped cardsview/recyclerview in the middle rather than it using the whole space.

Comment: @tony I just uploaded the tablet variation of the layout.  If you do not know how to create a tablet version let me know.  That is how it looks on the tablet and the other one on a phone.

Comment: Ah that's easier than I thought! From what I read I just need to put the files into the correct directories for the tablet version or do you mean anything specific?
I'm sorry I can't upvote you, yet as I do lack the required reputation. But I'll make sure to come back to this post once I earned it. 
And of course I'll accept your answer as the correct one, this seems to be a great starting point to further tinker with the layout.

Comment: If you are using android studio it is really easy to make other layout sizes.  In preview your click the button top right of the preview layout and choose the size

Comment: @tony Just posted another image showing where you click to create other layout variations.  Cheers!  You have any other questions on this just post it and let me know.

Comment: I played around with the code a bit more. I'd like to add that I believe it would be better to use "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" in the style.xml and "setSupportActionBar(toolbar)" in the MainActivity to make use of the new AppCompat Toolbar.

Comment: You could do that.  I prefer not to set for t as the actionbar because I have more control over it.